# Using open() on a thumb drive

Tags: c, file-io, filesystems, ext2

I have an EXT2 partition on my usb thumb drive and I can't get the C function open() to return anything other than -1.

Partition manager says that the partition is located at /dev/sdb2 and my code says

```
int fd = open("/dev/sdb2", O_RDONLY);
```

But after debugging, (fd == -1) and my usb notifier says that it isn't mounted before or after.

Side Note: the super-block and boot section seem to populate with values...

Comment: what is the value of `errno` after the failed open? (You do know that `open` will _not_ mount that partition, right? it'll attempt to open the block device directly, allowing you to read/write directly to the raw disk - very dangerous - if you have the right privileges)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't explain it well enough (I do know the purpose of open). How do I find errno?

Comment: `#include <errno.h>`, `#include <stdio.h>`, then after `open`, `if (fd == -1) { perror("open failed"); exit(1); }` or just `printf` `errno` (it's an int).

Comment: @Mat I used `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));` and got **Permission denied** how do I grant permission?

Comment: Check the permissions on `/dev/sdb2` and either run your code with a user that has the appropriate privileges (probably: root), or change the permissions on the device. **Warning** this is dangerous.

Comment: How do I change permissions on the device? I'm debugging in Netbeans so I don't know if I can run it with superuser permissions

Comment: @Eric Fossum: `chmod` works on block device special files just like it does on ordinary files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to open the thumb drive is correct in my question, but the program either needs to be run as super-user or `chmod 777 /dev/sdb2`

To see if this is your issue use the code above `printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));`

Answer (score 0):

Opening `/dev/sdb2` will open the raw block device accessing the partition on the thumb drive, which, if you have a filesystem on the partition, is not at all what you want to do.  You need to mount the  filesystem first, after which you can access files within it via the mount point.  Most linux systems will mount the thumb drive automatically when you plug it in -- if you type `mount` at the command line it will show you all the mounted filesystems and where they were mounted.  This will probably show you a line like:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/usb type ext2 (...
```

In which case you open `/media/usb/file` to access `file` in the root directory of the filesystem on the thumb drive.

If its not mounted automatically, you'll need to mount it manually before accessing it -- you can do that with the `mount` program or the mount(2) system call from within a program, but it generally requires superuser permissions.

Regardless of how you mount it, make sure to unmount it before unplugging the thumb drive to make sure that all the data has been written and is up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm writing a program to access and modify inodes. This requires `open()` and `read()`, Mat was right in that I needed to check my **errno** and act accordingly.